# 'npm install -g typescript' doesn't install correctly on windows (missing tsc.cmd)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, npm-install

Global install of typescript doesn't appear to install correctly on windows.

***Steps to reproduce:***

- .Using node v16.16.0 (64bit)
- .Then 'npm install -g typescript'
- .I can confirm environment path variables contain:
  '***C:\Users{MyUserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm***' and
  '***C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules***'

The node_modules/typescript/bin folder appears a follows:
[image: typescript Bin folder image]

- As seen, a tsc file does exist, however the expected tsc.cmd doesn't.
  This is required for windows to execute.
- My assumption is this must be system or permissions problem whereby node can't create the tsc.cmd, not necessarily and issue with the
  typescript package

***Image for reference:***
[image: Expected vs now]

//----------------

***Additional notes:***

- I have also tested this on 10.24.1 using nvm, this is now uninstalled
- I have ran these steps on another machine, without problems countless
  times.
- I have uninstalled (completely) nvm and node before attempting this
  multiple times.
- I have performed a complete system search for tsc.cmd I do have
  wsl installed, perhaps there is some interference there?

***Results from suggestions this far:***
[image: tsc execution image]

- Running locally on a project (Niceman)

Comment: Did you try just running `tsc` in a console on some file/project?

Comment: I did yes, thanks. I'll add that to the notes with pictures.

Comment: does `npm i -g typescript` throw any error of any kind?

Comment: Anyway you can just use local installation of typescript in the projects you need, that way you can configure its version per-project instead of having a global shared version.

Comment: npm -i -g typescript doesn't provide any errors.
As you can see, the package does install, but the *.cmd files for windows execution aren't created.

Comment: Local installation is exactly the same result I'm afraid

Comment: I think you can execute it by calling `node ./tsc` (in linux/macos `tsc` is just a JS file with executable permission, not sure about windows)

Comment: You said you successfully installed typescript on another machine, can you tell us the Windows version of both machines (with build number please e.g., Windows 10 19H2 not just Windows 10)

Comment: Also, does the machine that fails on you happen to BSOD lately?

Comment: @niceman No issues with the machine, it's fairly new, high end and all hardward diagnostics are fine.

The machine that works: windows version is: win 10 pro version 10.0.19044 Build 19044
The machine that doesn't: win 11 pro, version: 10.0.22000 Build 22000

Hope that helps somewhat, I'll run a windows update whilst I'm at it just in case..

Comment: @bogdanoff I'm afraid this doesn't work due to the nature of project needed to be built, but thanks.

Comment: Try `npm cache clean –force` and then install tsc

Comment: @niceman After running this command + npm i -g typescript. I get: 'changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s' With no tsc.cmd in the required folder or any other changes I can see :(

Comment: The screenshots compare C:\Users{MyUserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm to C:\Users{MyUserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin. You should look at same folder level.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue more related to your node path in your environment variables. To test this, install something else globally, like sass for example.

Then you can try sass --version. If it doesn't work the it's probably that your node path is messed up. You can try uninstalling node and reinstall it with the last LTS installing file from the official site. Then you can try to installing typescript again. If that doesn't work you'll need to open the environment variables and check your path for node modules.

Another possible solution is to try using another command line, because maybe a Powershell config is messing up this things. You can try installing git bash. It's not the best, but works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was one of the first steps I took I'm afraid.


I've removed all relevent path variables and tried adding the bare minimum - just 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' I've tried reinstalling the lts, newest and latest.|

I've also uninstalled/reinstalled nvm, Making sure I've deleted npm and nodejs folders between installs, (so a clean reinistall). 
Alas, no change. -Quite frustrating!

Comment: Please see the 'Image for reference:' in the question. I have the same result with sass: no installed {nodepackage}.cmd; meaning environment variables can't use anything!

Comment: Can you try to set this for your node path: 
At variable name, type in: NODE_PATH.
As for the variable value, type in: C:\Users\YOUR USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: this doesn't have any effect as the tsc.cmd doesn't exist, please see the images added to the original question explaining this.

Comment: Yeah I've seen the images. I have the same 2 files as you, I don't have any issue. I'm using nvm, node 16.15.1. Which npm version do you have? Maybe trying to update just npm and restarting your computer fixes the issue. What happens if you run npm i -g npm@latest?

Comment: I've tried with both nvm and standard install. I've ran npm i -g npm@latest, newest and lts. Along with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade. 


I fail to see how your installation can work without tsc.cmd on windows, that to my knowledge is how node modules are invoked on windows. If you do a 'where tsc' do  you see a tsc.cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **use yarn!**

As mentioned, I am missing tsc.cmd whatever method I choose (win 11). Who knows what the cause is.

By using yarn :

- Delete the dudd folder under your node_modules folder from any npm attempts
- yarn global remove typescript
- yarn global add typescript
- add 'C:\Users{yourUserName}\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules.bin' to your path

As mentiond, you now have the required tsc.cmd:
[image: tsc.cmd and version check]

*What a ride ey!*